# Uploading a file with ng-file-upload directive to a sails.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, file-upload, sails.js

I'm attempting to upload a file to a sails.js application server using this directive:
[ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

My client side to upload an already selected image is this:

```
$upload.upload({
        url:'upload/item-image',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        data:{blah:'blah'},
        file: $scope.uploadFile,
        fileName:$scope.uploadFile.name
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

And my sails.js controller method that handles the upload on the server starts like this:

```
upload: function (req, res) {
    req.file('item-image').upload(function (err, files) {
        if (err)
            return res.serverError(err);
        if(!files.length)
            return res.serverError('No files received for upload.');

        var file = files[0];
   ...
   }
...
}
```

However, while the server function is being called, and the json data on the body exists, no files are being found by req.file('no matter what put here') callback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sails but I had a similar situaion with express, I ended up by configuring a middleware to handle post/file on the request, I used busboy, maybe you can find a similar approach for sails

Comment: I'm guessing that you're not giving `req.file()` the right argument, namely the name of the field that the files are being uploaded under.  It's definitely not `item-image`.  Have you tried `req.file('file')`?

Comment: While I managed to find that out for myself eventually, yours is the correct solution, @sgress454 . Please write it as a full answer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: Also, @sgress454, as you seem to be a core contributor to sails.js, I would like to take a moment to tell you I love you :) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to `req.file` needs to be the name of the field in the request where Sails should look for the uploaded files.  If you're doing a simple HTML form with something like:

```
<input type="file" name="myFileField" />
```

then in your controller code you would have:

```
req.file('myFileField').upload(...);
```

With uploader widgets like the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) widget referenced in this question, it can sometimes be a little tricky to figure out what that field name is.  In this case it's hidden in the [usage instructions](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload):

> ```
> //fileFormDataName: myFile, // or a list of names for multiple files (html5). 
>                             // Default is 'file'
> ```

So you can set `fileFormDataName` to change the upload field name, or else it defaults to `file`.

If you can't find the field name in the docs or by inspecting the HTML, the easiest thing to do is just do an upload (even if it's unsuccessful) and inspect the network request using the developer tools in Chrome:

[image]

This is from the Angular file upload demo page.  You can see in the lower right where it says `name="myFile"`; that's what you're looking for.  In this case the file field is called `myFile`.

Answer (score 0):

one important thing, if you want to process more than one file in your backend using:

`req.file('files').upload({...});`

you need to add the `arrayKey: ''` parameter in your `Upload.upload({})` like this:

```
Upload.upload({
   url: 'http://localhost:1337/uploads',
   arrayKey: '',
   data: {
    files: files
   }
```